# ionic 2, "return" is not working

Tags: return, ionic2

```
  tamGetir(yno){
    let yazilan:any;

     let body={
           uyeno:this.uye.uyeno,
           eposta: this.uye.eposta,
           sifre: this.uye.sifre,
           gunlukno: this.defterno,
           yazino: yno
          }  
    this.http.post('http://www.gibigo.com/sayfalar/ion_android_gungetir2.php',JSON.stringify(body))
          .map(res=>res.json())
          .subscribe(data=>{

                 console.log(data.yazi);
                 yazilan=data.yazi;
           });
    return yazilan;
 }
```

"data.yazi" looks correct in console, but return operation does not work. Return is undifinied. How can i return it correct.

Comment: check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

The http function returns an *Observable*. This is asynchrounous. When you use subscribe, the http request is fired and an observable is returned. The data is received on response.

`yazilan=data.yazi;` is happening *after* the return statement.
You should use a class variable to simply save the data within the subscription.

If your method is in a provider, return the http call with map and subscribe in your component

```
 tamGetir(yno){
    let yazilan:any;

     let body={
           uyeno:this.uye.uyeno,
           eposta: this.uye.eposta,
           sifre: this.uye.sifre,
           gunlukno: this.defterno,
           yazino: yno
          }  
    return this.http.post('http://www.gibigo.com/sayfalar/ion_android_gungetir2.php',JSON.stringify(body))
          .map(res=>res.json())
```

In your component:

```
yazi:any;//class variable

callHttpFunction(){
  this.provider.tamGetir(yno)
   .subscribe(data=>{//call the subsribe
              console.log(data);
              this.data_variable =data.yazi;
              })
}
```